# Why did Obi-Wan..?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope

> Why did Obi-Wan let Vader kill him?

I know he said he would become more powerful if Vader struck him down, but I don't know why. The only answer I have seen is to allow Luke time to escape, but I don't think that is it.

Answer (score 4):

He was going to become "more powerful than Vader could possibly imagine" because he was going to leave his body behind and merge with the Light Side of the Force Because of this, death wasn't something he feared or was particularly trying to avoid.